# Getting json object data into html front end in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I am returning a JSON array Object from an external API which I want to show in the HTML view on Angular front-end. But the view is not loading with below error

Output in console

ERROR Error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."
ERROR CONTEXT 
Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 3, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }

```
getGifs() {
this.getData().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.data = data;
})
}
```

In console logs I can see result as,

```
data: Array(25) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … 
meta: Object { status: 200, msg: "OK", response_id:       "5cea7c49386968693259fc04" }
pagination: Object { total_count: 2447, count: 25, offset: 0 }
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

How can I read this data variable in my HTML page. Tried iterating with ngfor but it fails.

Comment: can you post the JSON of console.log(this.data)l

Comment: data: (25) […]
​​
0: Object { type: "gif", id: "bVeC916JLikZG", slug: "steve-carell-bVeC916JLikZG", … }
​​
1: Object { type: "gif", id: "jHF49Bz9btG1O", slug: "jHF49Bz9btG1O", … }
​​
2: Object { type: "gif", id: "Ij1cbMbIWDKDK", slug: "get-reasons-mcadams-Ij1cbMbIWDKDK", … }
​​
3: Object { type: "gif", id: "l0IsIk6AUy69wVU2c", slug: "snl-saturday-night-live-ryan-gosling-l0IsIk6AUy69wVU2c", … }
​​
4: Object { type: "gif", id: "wMvESGxZ0Cqd2", slug: "frustrated-ryan-gosling-wMvESGxZ0Cqd2", … }
​
​​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the data property of the response to render on the HTML,

```
this.data = data.data;
```

and render in HTML as

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of data">
       {{item.type}}. {{item.slug}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

EDIT

```
this.getData().subscribe((data:any) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.data = data.data;
})
```

Comment: this.data = data.data?

data property wont exist on data right?

Comment: As i see your response contains the data property

Comment: But it doesn't show. I changed method as below,

    getGifs() {
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.data = data.data;
      })
     }

But it gives error property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: change .subscribe((data:any) =>

Comment: See the data variable declared was 

     data : any ={};

     constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { 
     console.log("Hello");
     this.getGifs();
     this.getData();
     }

      getData() {
     return this.httpClient.get(this.searchapiUrl);
    }

      getGifs() {
        this.getData().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data.data;
      })
     }

If I change as you said it still gives the same error.

Comment: oh no! i was mentioning on the subscribe part, check the edited answer

Comment: Thanks now it works. Just one more question, I see the list now. But actually this JSON objects holds the GIF images but this just list the elements not shows the image on HTML. Do we have to do some adaptations for that?

Comment: not sure, you need to check one by one and bind it using the img attribute. mark if this helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193952/discussion-between-sourav-mehra-and-sajeetharan).